She's a black belt in judo

She's a black belt in judo. (source: judo)

Is She's a contraction of "She has" or "She is"? At first sight, I thought She's was a contraction of "She has", but I just found the following sentence:

He is a black belt in karate. (source: karate)

I don't know why this sentence is possible. It seems illogical to me.

Intuitively, using "She is a black belt in judo" is not much more illogical than the common Japanese joke "watashi wa unagi desu", the "is" doesn't necessarily mean that the person is literally a belt.

@justhalf But surely, everyone who has watched Friends knows what unagi means? ;-) As Ross points out, it's not something you have but something you are (unless I misremember it).

Both "is" and "has" are grammatically correct. According to this NGram graph, "has" is more common, but "she's" is generally an abbreviation for "she is" rather than "she has", so I would interpret "She's" as "She is" in your sentence.
Black belt is a rank in martial arts grading systems, in the same way as sergeant or corporal are army ranks. The two sentences below are therefore equivalent.

He is a sergeant in the army
She is a black belt in Judo

A black belt can also be regarded as a qualification, so the following sentences are also equivalent:

She has a degree in physics
She has a black belt in Judo


It's also a literal belt in some cases, so the possessive could be appropriate to that.

Commenting on your answer because it's highest-upvoted currently. I just wanted to emphasize (because OP used the transatlantic-differences tag) that there is a difference between AmE and BrE here. In BrE it might be true that "she's" can be either "she is" or "she has." But in AmE it is exceedingly rare for "she's" to be "she has." It is (nearly) always going to be "she is."

Thank you, randomhead. I did not use the transatlantic-differences tag. It seems that someone added it. According to a Japanese teacher of English, Americans do not say "I've a pen" or "Have you a pen?".

@Kaguyahime Americans would almost always add the word "got" to those sentences. "I've got a pen" or "Have you got a pen?" On the other hand, without the abbreviation it would be more common without "got"- "I have a pen," "Do you have a pen?"

@randomhead as a BrE speaker, I am not sure there's much difference here. I think is also extremely rare in BrE for "she's" to mean "she has" in this sense. In my experience, "she has" would only be contracted when followed by a past participle.

@randomhead I am aware that there are differences between AmE and BrE in the usage of have, got and contractions. I didn't mention it in my answer because a) as Kaguyahime says, there was no transatlantic-differences tag when I answered the question and b) my comment about relative usage of contractions of "she is" and "she has" apply in both  BrE and AmE... contracted "she has" is pretty uncommon in both.

Check out the figure of speech called "metonymy"  It's where you replace the word for something by an attribute.
Here is a paper: Metonymies we (don’t) translate by The case of complex metonymies Whether a particular metonmyn translates to your language will affect whether you think it is "logical" or not. If you language happens not to use "black belt" in the same way  (IIRC, in Japanese you would say ichidanshodan="start step" and not kuroiobi="belt that is black") then it would seem illogical.
Some examples are saying "He's first violin in the orchestra" or (thinking about the Olympics "Tola won gold in the marathon."  In both cases logically they don't make sense.  He isn't a violin.  Tola won a race; Tola won a medal (that was made with gold).
It's just the same with "black belt" The object stands for the person who has earned it. So "He's"= "He is" is correct.

The OP's example is "She's a black belt in Judo". Is it still metonymy when we add a different subject and  an object complement? Compare: The crown's in crisis (The British monarchy's in crisis). Can we equally say "She's [part of] the crown"?  As for "gold" it's just short for "a gold medal" i.e. Tola won a gold [medal] Where is the metonymy? Certainly, you can win a prize that is "made of" gold.

Whether a particular metonymmy is common or not is a matter of idiom.  We don't tend to say "She's a crown"  But we might say "She's one of the crowned heads of Europe" or something like that.  Of course "gold" is short for "gold medal".  That is the essence of metonmy, you shortern an expression by referring to it by one of it's attributes.

But without context that "won gold" could be anything, how do we know it's an Olympic medal? It could be a gold platter, trophy, chain, or watch. When we talk about the White House or 10 Downing Street we instantly know what is being referred to.

You only know from context.

…by referring to it by one of it's [its] attributes "England last won the world cup in 1966" how is England an attribute? Maybe you're thinking of synecdoche? Or maybe I am??

Yes, maybe I am,  The two concepts are similar enough and fuzzy enough for me not to worry too much about it.

Note that in many Japanese martial arts, 'first ranking' would be expressed as Shodan, not ichidan.

Would you mind if I asked a question on EL&U about metonymy and citing your answer? Hopefully a detailed and longer answer will explain why a "black belt" is not only an achievement but can also be used as a synecdoche/metonymy.

Sure, you might want to refer to the source mentioned in this answer too.

I don't know if you've visited the EL&U question but suffice to say we do not have a unanimous agreement that "black belt", in the sentence "She's a black belt in Judo", is a metonym.

In American English, in that particular example, it it understood to be a contraction for "is".
It's like saying "She's a lieutenant", as "black belt" is understood to be a rank that is represented visually with a black belt.
In American English, if we wanted to say that she possesses a black belt, or has been promoted to that rank using the verb has, we wouldn't contract but would say

She has a black belt in judo.

This doesn't happen in American English with has when it is not used as an auxiliary verb but the lexical verb meaning "possess, own":

She's a cat and two dogs.

But we do contract with the auxiliary verb:

She's been there many times.

And when the meaning is something other than "possess, own" then we will often contract:

Sorry, can't talk now. I've a meeting to go to.


I don't see a fat lot of difference between BrE I've a cheque and AmE I've a check. It's essentially just OP's specific context that makes the difference, and that would apply for all Anglophones.

@FumbleFingers Thanks once again for schooling me on American English, a language I've been speaking for decades. For those who might not know, you're a Brit. We murkins strongly favor uncontracted have when it's the lexical verb but use the contracted form with the auxiliary. In American English  "I've a dog" is rare compared to "I have a dog".   You'll hear "I've a dog" down south more than elsewhere.

A lexical verb where the meaning is "possess, own".

As for Ngram, it's "distinction" between BrE and AmE is total shite. You cannot rely on it for anything.  Take a look at the actual texts that lie behind those numbers some day.

@FumbleFingers There's a significant leap between I've a cheque/check and the version with "got" i.e. I've got a check:

I've seen Dickens show up when searching American English,  because the edition was published in Boston.

I don't dispute that AmE prefers not to contract have in such contexts. I'm simply saying the same applies to BrE, so it's potentially misleading to repeat American English three times in this answer. It's quite true that relative prevalence shown by NGrams is affected by the fact that AmE is more likely to include got, but that's not relevant to my point.

It's also irrelevant that some texts are misattributed between BrE/AmE, since (1) most are correctly attributed, and (2) my chart didn't use the assigned attribution - it used the spelling distinction.

@FumbleFingers The distinction I made with respect to American English is that the OP's specific example would be understood as "is" in American English.The OP's question is specifically about the contraction.  We would not understand it to mean has.

A statistically signficant number of texts are misattributed, IMO.  Ngrams is not a good comparison engine for BrE/AmE. It's good for some diachronic analysis and for finding out whether a particular construction is valid.

I think Google Ngram viewer is useful if we're willing to go into the sources. I'm American who would never contract "She has" to "She's" when "has" is a possessive verb but I've observed one American do that. Seeing the stats of the two n-grams is enough reason to look at the results and see if this contraction is more common than I though.

Another thing to notice is that "I'm a black belt" is about as common as "I'm a runner" but "I've a black belt" is not found at all.

@TimR No-one is disputing that everything you say is true for American English. The point FumbleFingers is making is that it is equally true for British English. Therefore including the caveat "in American English" in your answer is not necessary and could be misleading.

@EspeciallyLime  But how am I to know if it is equally true for BrE?  It is incumbent upon a BrE speaker to add an answer that says so, and people can upvote or downvote that answer to corroborate its validity or not.  I did not say it was not also true for BrE.  What I did was state only what I know to be the case..


She is (or has) a black belt in judo.

Both interpretations are possible.
Is a black belt in is a common usage and has many pages of hits.
We could interpret the OP’s example as

She is a black belt (exponent) in judo.


“A black belt” is something you are, where you have qualifications, often in a figurative sense, meaning you are very good at something. It is also something you have; a physical belt in black Color.
Now imagine this lady kept the blue belt that she received three years earlier. You would say “she has her blue belt still at the bottom of her wardrobe”. You wouldn’t say “she’s a blue belt”.
Now imagine another woman, not a lady, who has stolen a physical black belt or bought one on a jumble sale. She is not a black belt. You wouldn’t say “she’s a black belt” as an abbreviation for “she has a black belt”.

In British English the contraction, denoting possession, would commonly be:

She's got a black belt in judo. (She has got a …) YES
She's got her own flat in London. (YES)
She has her own flat in London. (YES)
She's her own flat in London (COLLOQUIAL)

Consequently, in British English, the contraction ‘s without got is more likely to stand for

She is a black belt in Judo.

We use the linking verb be to describe a person or thing; e.g., he's a mathematician, she's Spanish, dinner's ready, the trees are particularly old etc.

EDIT 11th August
I don't mind criticism or challenges, seriously I don't, as long as the tone is respectful. Compare the tone between the two commenters below, I much prefer the second.
Some attention has been directed to the last example, “She's her own flat in London", it is AWKWARD but that was by choice. I deliberately composed it that way to illustrate how the contraction she’s could mislead the reader into initially thinking “She is her own flat…”, which is obviously nonsensical. Although the word own emphasises possession, the contracted form is awkward on paper despite being perfectly grammatical. In speech and in everyday writing, she's got avoids this sore point.

No results found for "She's her own flat". The contraction I've a house {in London} was already becoming at least "dated" by the mid-1800s. Why do so many people think British English ceased to change after Dickens?

@FumbleFingers perhaps you need to be reminded that Google Books is an unreliable source for speech.

You seem to agree with TimR that he's entitled to claim special knowledge of AmE because he's American. Why do you suppose the same doesn't apply to me? I've a house in London is the sort of thing you'll hear in TV period drama, not when talking to current property owners in SE UK.

@FumbleFingers I find "I've a house in London" to be perfectly natural, and would not feel I was a time traveller. But I would say "I've got a house in London" to be more common in British English.

“I’ve a house” - it would never occur to me to contract like this.  “I’ve got a house OToH is very natural. (BrE). “I have a house” is also quite common.

But you're not a native Anglophone! And the chart in y first comment clearly shows how that particular abbreviated form has fallen out of favour over the past two centuries. I have to repeat: She's her own flat in London isn't remotely "colloquial" today - it's an affectation.

“Why do so many people think British English ceased to change after Dickens?” Because the only British novelist since Dickens that is popularly read in the US writes almost exclusively about wizards and monsters...
